# Wire Length Restrictions on Simple Battery Powered Circuit

Tags: circuit-design, wire, gauge

Right now I am setting up a simple circuit with a switch at one end and a LED on the other. Basically it is going to be used for someone on one end to get the attention of the person on the other. The distance from one end to the other is approaching 50 feet.

I would like to set it up on an AA battery, or two if needed, but I do not know if the distance would be prohibitive. If necessary I will add in an RF transmitter and receiver but would rather not, since it would add to the bulk on the end with the button and I want to build it to be small and easily hidden. I can route the wire out of sight without a problem.

So being an amateur with electronics I thought I would ask here. Is that length going to be a problem? If so can I increase the size of the battery to overcome it? What gauge wire should I use? I am a Network Admin so I have boxes of 22 gauge CAT6 kicking around that I could use, is that heavy enough or is it too heavy?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For 50 ft, your #22 CAT6 cable should be fine.

The resistance of #22 wire is about 16 Ohms per 1000 ft, or 1.6 Ohms for your 50 ft there-and-back. The wire will only carry 20 mA or so for a standard LED, giving a voltage drop in the cable of 0.03 volts.